# Trigger Change on UIViewController from UITableView(WEPopover)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` and I am using the `WEPopover` controls to generate a drop-down on the view controller.  The content for the `WEPopover` is held in a `UITableViewController`.  The `WEPopover` is triggered when a `UIImageView` is pressed on the main `UIViewController`

[WEPopover GitHub Link](https://github.com/PaulSolt/WEPopover)

I am aware that once a row in the table is selected the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` triggers.  Where I am facing a challenge is taking the result of the selected row, and then triggering a change on the main `UIViewController`.

What I am attempting to do is take the string in the row I have selected in the `UITablewViewController`, and then apply that string value (Hex String, using UIColor Extended from GitHub to convert to UIColor)as the new color overlay of the `UIImageView` which is located on the `UIViewController`

Comment: You probably should hack the WEPopover and implement a WEPopoverTableViewDelegate protocol. Then declare your main UIViewController conform to this protocol (see the answer of Mohannad). Or use the NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can define a delegate `protocol` for your `UITableViewController`, and a method, such as `- (void) tableViewControllerDidChooseValue:(id)sender`.

Make the main view controller conform to that `protocol`. Upon showing the `UITableViewController`, add the main view controller as the delegate for the `UITableViewController`.

Once `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, call the delegate (main view controller)'s method with the updated value.

You may use this as a chance to dismiss the `UITableViewController`.